# “dass d__ Leute sehen können” – why “die” and not “den”?

Tags: grammatical-case

I am learning genitive case. I got this sentence from an online worksheet.

> Ich möchte nicht, dass d__ Leute in mein_ Wohnung sehen können.

What I learnt for finding the genitive is to ask *whom.*
Here I asked *whom* and found the answer *Leute,* so I put the article as *den* (as *Leute* is plural).
But the answer given by site is:

> Ich möchte nicht, dass **die** Leute in meine Wohnung sehen können.

What is the mistake in my logic?

Comment: You're not asking for the genitive by *whom*. You should use *whose*.

Comment: @tofro so shouldn't it be die Leute in meiner Whonung...? whose gives Whonung?

Comment: No. *whose* gives "meine"

Comment: Sorry, but still it is meiner right?

Comment: nope. It's meine.

Comment: To add something to the confusion: It COULD be meiner... but then the meaning would be different...`in meine Wohnung sehen` = `look into my flat`, `in meiner Wohnung sehen` = `see something, when they are in my flat, e.g. because it is to dark`

Comment: @TorstenLink  : Actually what I meant in the question was dative. I noticed it just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused by the main clause and the sub-clause in your example. Rip this apart before you start to analyse cases.

Your main clause is simple:

> Ich möchte nicht.

And your sub-clause, re-formed into a main clause:

> Die Leute können in meine Wohnung sehen.

So the subject of your sub-clause is "Leute", which clearly has to be nominative, so "die Leute". Now, what's with the flat: That's *mine*, so genitive? No. It's "in meine Wohnung", and "in" is a preposition that rules the clause here. "In" can either rule dative or accusative, here it's denoting a motion (of the view) *towards something*, so accusative.

Put everything back together:

> Ich möchte nicht, dass die Leute in meine Wohnung sehen können.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually making a series of mistakes here:

- The German genitive case mostly corresponds to the English genitive case, which in turn answers to *whose* (not *whom*). Note that this does not always hold.
- If you are asking for *people* with *whom* in English, you are using a different sentence construction, I suppose:

  > I do not want people to look into my flat.

  Here, *people* is indeed in the oblique case and you would ask for it with *whom.* However, the English sentence that most closely reflects the grammatical structure of the German sentence is:

  > I do not want that (the) people can look into my flat.

  Here *people* is in the substantive case and you would ask for it with *who.* The same applies in German: *Leute* is the subject of a subordinate clause and hence in the nominative case. This subordinate clause transforms into a main clause as follows:

  > Die Leute können in meine Wohnung sehen.
  >   (People can look into my flat.)
- Also, the genitive of *die Leute* is *der Leute. Den* is the article for the dative case, which is *den Leute**n**.*